# iPad locks up (stuck in update loop)

Tags: loops, ipad, lockup

I'm getting the following error message and my app locks up.

"Collection view <UpdateCoalescingCollectionView 0x283d5c870> is stuck in its update loop."

My app runs fine on my iPhone but locks up on my iPad.  Same code.  No checking for device anywhere in my code.

Using SwiftUI. iPad OS 17.2. Xcode 15.0

Any help would be appreciated.

This happens randomly.  Once when I was entering text into a search bar, again (after rebuilding) while just scrolling a list.